# Where to place raw custom SQL queries in Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have a simple **views.py** file

```
from django.db import connection
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response


class UsersView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM users")
            users_data = cursor.fetchall()

        return Response(users_data)

    def post(self, request):
        """
        {"username": "Ivan", "bio": "Hi I am Ivan"}
        """
        data = request.data
        username = data.get('username')
        bio = data.get('bio')

        with connection.cursor() as cursor:
            cursor.execute("INSERT INTO users (username, bio) VALUES (%s, %s)", [username, bio])

        return Response("Ok")
```

I am wondering how to organize my code when using raw SQL queries. I understand that the functionality demonstrated in my code can be easily achieved using the Django ORM; this is just an illustration. Should I concentrate all query logic within the **`serializers.py`** file, or would it be preferable to create a separate file for this purpose? **Could you guide me or provide a resource that explains how to organize this?**

Comment: Do you need an authentication system or is it just a user table to save bio without login, register etc ?

Comment: @Zatigem Hi. No, there is no need for the authentication. I am just curious how to organize all this stuff. This is just a user table to save bio without login, register etc

Comment: You can do that but make a separate file is a best way